# ActiveMq(version: 5.7) client connection getting set/resetting very frequently

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

We are experiencing a very typical issue where `ActiveMq`(integrated camel) client connection getting set/resetting very frequent for some period, due to which application which uses the jms connection does not work properly for the down town.

After the period, connections are getting refreshed successfully. We are not finding any clue on why connections go down in between. `ActiveMq` running single mode(one broker and no cluster)

I could see all tcp sockets are up with netstat command.

Please find the below errors.

```
2015-08-20 23:49:08,084 | WARN  | al-01/10.224.240.109:61616@41545 | CachingConnectionFactory         | 135 - org.springframework.jms - 3.0.7.RELEASE | Encountered a JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection 
javax.jms.JMSException: java.io.EOFException 
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:49)[177:org.apache.activemq.activemq-core:5.7.0.1-SNAPSHOT] 
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onAsyncException(ActiveMQConnection.java:1949)[177:org.apache.activemq.activemq-core:5.7.0.1-SNAPSHOT] 
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onException(ActiveMQConnection.java:1966)[177:org.apache.activemq.activemq-core:5.7.0.1-SNAPSHOT] 
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:101)[177:org.apache.activemq.activemq-core:5.7.0.1-SNAPSHOT] 
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.onException(ResponseCorrelator.java:126)[177:org.apache.activemq.activemq-core:5.7.0.1-SNAPSHOT] 
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:101)[177:org.apache.activemq.activemq-core:5.7.0.1-SNAPSHOT] 
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:101)[177:org.apache.activemq.activemq-core:5.7.0.1-SNAPSHOT] 
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.onException(WireFormatNegotiator.java:160)[177:org.apache.activemq.activemq-core:5.7.0.1-SNAPSHOT] 
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onException(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:295)[177:org.apache.activemq.activemq-core:5.7.0.1-SNAPSHOT] 
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.onException(TransportSupport.java:96)[177:org.apache.activemq.activemq-core:5.7.0.1-SNAPSHOT] 
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.nio.NIOTransport.serviceRead(NIOTransport.java:98)[177:org.apache.activemq.activemq-core:5.7.0.1-SNAPSHOT] 
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.nio.NIOTransport$1.onSelect(NIOTransport.java:69)[177:org.apache.activemq.activemq-core:5.7.0.1-SNAPSHOT] 
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.nio.SelectorSelection.onSelect(SelectorSelection.java:94)[177:org.apache.activemq.activemq-core:5.7.0.1-SNAPSHOT] 
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.nio.SelectorWorker$1.run(SelectorWorker.java:119)[177:org.apache.activemq.activemq-core:5.7.0.1-SNAPSHOT] 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)[:1.7.0_65] 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)[:1.7.0_65] 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)[:1.7.0_65] 
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
```

---

Sometimes its refusing client connection like below

```
2015-08-20 23:49:13,138 | WARN  | er[MONITORING_ping_itg://itg:13] | faultJmsMessageListenerContainer | 135 - org.springframework.jms - 3.0.7.RELEASE | Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'temporary' - retrying in 5000 ms. Cause: Could not connect to broker URL: nio://msc-pcen-portal-01:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Can you please somebody comment on it what are the possibilities of client connection resets as our application completely relying on reliability of the connection. If it is the expected behavior with JMS broker, can you list any solutions to the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check for firewall, load balancer etc which can disconnect your client.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your reply, but  I want to clarify you that there is no load balancer configured and noticed that the issue is observed only during some sync operations(operation pulls data from different servers).